Windows 10 NTP polling from second ethernet interface
My setup is a Windows 10 Enterprise machine running as a server for a Phone system.  I have a wired ethernet interface that is used to control the phone system as a SIP server.  I also have a WiFi dongle, so I can access the internet.
The wired interface cannot access the internet and is used exclusively as the local SIP server.  It is on it's own private network.
The WiFi dongle to access the internet is used for remote purposes and to intermittently access the internet.  The Wifi is behind a hardware firewall that I do not have access to (nor do I want to).  Windows Firewall is turned off.
I have the "Set time automatically" enabled in the Date and Time settings.  I have the "Set time zone automatically" enabled as well.
In the "Internet Time Settings", I have the Synchronize with an Internet time server checkbox on, set to time.windows.com.
However when the update now button is clicked I get "An error occurred getting the status of the last synchronization. Element not found."
The time does not update.
I suspect that the internet time is trying to use the hardwired interface that does not connect to the internet instead of trying to use the WiFi dongle.
How can I force Windows 10 to use the Wifi instead of the hardwire interface?

Do you have a Default Gateway set on the wired interface? What other routes do you have through the wired interface? (Have you considered getting a 2nd wired Ethernet interface?)

Use Route print in a command window to find out which destinations are currently routed through which interface. The issue may be something else entirely, so you should try to rule that out.

I would not be able to install a wired interface on the PBX CPU as that would invalidate the warranty from the PBX manufacturer.  Since this controls a hotel, the system must not go down for life/safety issues.
The wired interface does have a gateway set on it, as the firewall also serves out DHCP to the SIP phones.  The wired interface also looks to the firewall to resolve addressing of the SIP lines to the PBX.  The SIP lines are direct Point to Point with no internet, between the Carrier and SIP line interface.
